# Data Points for Path to draw a tick mark

Tags: wpf, xaml, styling

Can anyone specify the data points to be used to get a tick mark like the following

[image]

I use this

```
<Path Name="TickMark" Fill="Black" Data="M0,4 5,9 9,0 4,5" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

But doesnt look like the above,It looks like

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you need an specific path, I recommend to use Inkscape or Expression Design and try to make by yourself

For this case, I have made it in Inkscape and pasted into Expression Design:

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="Layer_1" Width="8" Height="9" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0">
<Path Width="7.85446" Height="8.57578" Canvas.Left="-0.0522281" Canvas.Top="-0.100391" Stretch="Fill" StrokeThickness="1.04192" StrokeMiterLimit="2.75" Stroke="#FF000000" Data="F1 M 0.468732,4.66838L 3.03345,7.95443L 7.28127,0.420569"/>
```

Then extract the Data to your Path

```
<Path Name="TickMark" Fill="Black" Data="F1 M 0.468732,4.66838L 3.03345,7.95443L 7.28127,0.420569" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

And just adjust until you like the tick mark